javascript find value by key in nested object
I am trying to make a function for recursive searching an object by key and valule.
I can't figure out how to this and tried different examples.
Can anyone help me out?
I have this object:
var menuObj = {
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id" : 72,
            "menu_id" :1 ,
            "parent_id" : 0,
            "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"post-page\",\"routeParams\":{\"slug\":\"algemene-voorwaarden\"}}",
            "permission" : null,
            "hierarchie" : 0,
            "blank" : 0,
            "status" : "published",
            "label" : "Algemene Voorwaarden",
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "id" : 73,
            "menu_id" : 1,
            "parent_id" : 0,
            "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"post-page\",\"routeParams\":{\"slug\":\"privacy\"}}",
            "permission" : null,
            "hierarchie" : 1,
            "blank" : 0,
            "status" : "published",
            "label" : "Privacy",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : 101,
                    "menu_id" : 1,
                    "parent_id" : 73,
                    "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"blog\"}",
                    "permission" : null,
                    "hierarchie" : 2,
                    "blank" : 0,
                    "status" : "published",
                    "label" : "blog",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 102,
                            "menu_id" : 1,
                            "parent_id" : 101,
                            "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"blog\",\"routeParams\":{\"category_slug\":\"categorie-2\"}}",
                            "permission" : null,
                            "hierarchie" : 3,
                            "blank" : 0,
                            "status" : "published",
                            "label" : "Categorie 2",
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

Let say I need something like this:
fnFindKeyValuePair(obj, key, value) {
    // return true/false/null/undefined or found obj
}

Search examples:
fnFindKeyValuePair(menuObj['mainmenu'], 'href', "{\"routeName\":\"blog\"}")

Expected result: return true-ish or:
{
    "id" : 101,
    "menu_id" : 1,
    "parent_id" : 73,
    "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"blog\"}",
    "permission" : null,
    "hierarchie" : 2,
    "blank" : 0,
    "status" : "published",
    "label" : "blog",
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : 102,
            "menu_id" : 1,
            "parent_id" : 101,
            "href" : "{\"routeName\":\"blog\",\"routeParams\":{\"category_slug\":\"categorie-2\"}}",
            "permission" : null,
            "hierarchie" : 3,
            "blank" : 0,
            "status" : "published",
            "label" : "Categorie 2",
            "children" : []
        }
    ]
}


"I tried different examples" ... Can you show what you tried? Because all you are showing now is data structures.

Please follow this answer.

See: Find object from an array of nested objects by key in JavaScript, you can adjust the predicate to be (o) => o.href == "{\"routeName\":\"blog\"}", or more generically, o => o[key] == val if you want key and val to be arguments.

I did it like this:
static find_by_id(obj, key, value ) {
    if (obj[key] === value) {
        return obj
    }

     for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {            
        if(v && typeof(v) === 'object') {
            let x = find_by_id(v, key, value) 

            if (x) {
                return x
            }
        }
    }
}

